# Programmatically move Cursor to a TextBlock

Tags: wpf, keyboard, focus, textblock

in my application I'm opening a Window as a dialog. Inside this window, there's a TextBox called "myText". When the dialog is shown, I want the cursor to be automatically inside the "myText" TextBox, so the user can immediately enter something without having to click in the TextBox. I however have problems realising this, can somebody please help me with this?
Thank you very much for any hint!

Comment: Is that a TextBox you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or myText.Focus() in your Loaded event

Answer (score 3):

Set the [FocusManager.FocusedElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.focusedelement.aspx) property on your Window:

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=myText}"
```

Comment: Didn't try that because Nirs solution worked, anyways thanks for your reply!